# Run package's gulp task within my gulp task

Tags: gulp, node-modules

Is there a way to run a packages gulp task from within my gulp task? Here's my file structure:

```
Root
|
|-- Gulpfile.js (task: get-files)
|
|-- node_modules
     |
     |-- packageA
          |
          |-- gulpfile.js (task: compile-custom)
```

I want to run the `compile-custom` task from `packageA` from within my `get-files` task in my own gulpfile. Ideally, I could also get a callback from the `compile-custom` task to know when it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against running a task from another gulpfile as you want, especially from a node_modules package. A reason to not wanting to do so is due to the fact that the package can change/update and then break your code because of it.

Preferably you should just copy the gulpfile task you want into either your gulpfile and incorporate it into your project or just create a new file where you can easily distinguish that it is something separate from your gulpfile and just call it by requiring it in your own gulfile just like you would any other package and/or JS function. With either of these options do not forget to install the dependencies into your `package.json` files and then run `npm install`.

---

**Note:** To run a gulp task from within a gulp task you can use

`gulp.start('taskname')`

Although the following should be used only if completely necessary. In addition will be deprecated in the newer version of Gulp v4 ([refer to this](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/426)). The way to call a task is through just creating a function as mentioned above and calling that function in your gulpfile.

---

Example of gulp function calling:

```
 var someFile = require('./someFile.js'); 

 gulp.task('my-custom-task', function () {
   someFile.doSomething('foo', 'bar');
 });
```

If your function does something asynchronously, it should call a callback at the end, so gulp is able to know when it’s done:

```
 var someFile = require('./someFile.js'); 

 gulp.task('my-custom-task', function (callback) {
   someFile.doSomething('foo', 'bar', callback);
 });
```

Comment: I can understand the concern. My goal was to make this a single gulp task for simplicity's sake. My plan was to run `packageA`, which outputs a file to `packageA`'s `dist` directory. From there, I grab that file and put it in my project's `js` directory, hence the need for synchronous calls.

Comment: If you want to synchronize the calls and you need to know when the last task is finished i recommend you look into the [Run-Sequence Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence). You just put things in the order you want and they will run in a sequence where once you finish one task you will move on to the next. Which in your case seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try some combination of this solution and get back to you.